# How do I change the default view in kate?

Tags: kate

Whenever I open a file with Kate, Kate opens in Split view showing the same file twice. Does any of you guys know how to turn split-view off by default? it's really annoying to turn it off manually everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not a bug, its a "feature"!*

Kate remembers the last view you had open when you save a document and tries to restore it as it was from it.

To revert that effect you need to close the current views using the *View* > *Split View* > *Close Current View* menu and then use the *Sessions* > *Save Session* option.

After you have done this Kate will open with a the session as you left it.